# Ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10 got stuck in "Removing xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 (3:14.1)"

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I'm in the process of upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTE to Ubuntu 18.10. I've started [`do-release-upgrade`](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-ubuntu-18-10) from inside a GNOME Terminal window. It made some progress but now got stuck in `Removing xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 (3:14.1)`. How can I make progress from here on? (Maybe the problem is that the installer tries removing the X Server while it is still required for running GNOME Terminal.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to interrupt `do-release-upgrade` (after confirming that it remained stuck for an entire weekend). Afterwards, `cat /etc/os-release` indicated that the Ubuntu 8.10 was already present.

For good measure, I opened a virtual terminal, issued `systemctl stop $(basename $(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager))`, and repeated `do-release-upgrade`.

After `reboot` the upgrade now seems complete.